problem with \pgfcalendarcurrentdate
I try to create a calender and use pgfcalendar for that.
My simple code works but it breaks when using \pgfcalendarcurrentdate I do not understand why...
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\begin{document}
    
    \newcount\julianday

    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\pgfcalendarcurrentdate}{\julianday}
    
    The Julian day number for \today, is \the\julianday.
    
\end{document}

Error message is: ! Paragraph ended before \pgfcalendar@datetojulian was complete.

The first error I get is ! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pgfcalendarcurrentdate

@DavidCarlisle: You are right. That is the first one. I missed that... But why is that error there?

You could use \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-\month-\day}{\julianday}

I have no idea about the package, does it document that that command is defined?

As shown in the examples in section "89.1.1 Conversions Between Date Types" of the doc, you can use \year-\month-\day to refer to today.
If you are inside a calender, you could also directly use \pgfcalendarcurrentjulian.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar}

\begin{document}

    \newcount\julianday

    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\year-\month-\day}{\julianday}
    
    The Julian day number for \today, is \the\julianday.
    
    \tikz\calendar[dates=\year-\month-\day to \year-\month-\day, day text=\the\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian];
    
\end{document}


Thank you for the tipp! What do you mean "inside of a calender"?

@mrCarnivore `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {calendar}
\begin{document}
\tikz \calendar[dates=2000-01-01 to 2000-01-31,week list,
day text=\the\pgfcalendarcurrentjulian];
\end{document}`
